# Cadquery: how to create holes on multiple faces of a box?

Tags: python, cad, cadquery

I am trying to create holes on multiple faces of created box.

```py
import cadquery as cq
s = cq.Workplane().box(200,100,25)
s = (s
     .faces("<X")
    .workplane()
    .pushPoints([(10, 0)])
    .cboreHole(5, 6, 10,depth=10)
    .faces(">Z")
    .workplane()
    .pushPoints([(0, 10)])
    .cboreHole(5,6,10,depth=10)

)

show_object(s)
```

The code works fine if we keep either half of logic from `faces` to `cboreHole`, but fails when combined.
I tried different approaches to try to refer to the main box when creating the second hole, including `tag/workplaneFromTagged`, but none works.

Comment: I figured it out. The trick is to replace workplane() with .workplane(centerOption="CenterOfBoundBox"). Default is ProjectedOrigin, which only by pure luck behaves the same on the first call to workplane() just after creating a box().

Comment: You can add the solution as an answer.